# Google App Engine - adding an index

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

We had a class of Google App Engine (in Python), where the field is_admin was not indexed. We want it to be indexed now so we can filter the users by role - administrator or not administrator (is_admin true or false). The original class was like this:

```
class DomainUser(db.Expando, ExpandoEntity, SocialIconsEntity):
    """
    User domain DB Model
    """
    domain = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    ...
    is_admin = db.BooleanProperty(default=False, indexed=False)
    ...
```

And I changed it to this:

```
    class DomainUser(db.Expando, ExpandoEntity, SocialIconsEntity):
    """
    User domain DB Model
    """
    domain = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    ...
    is_admin = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
    ...
```

But I read in the documentation that we have to save each object again for the index to be created. Is it possible to create the index without saving all the objects again? We filter all the users by a specific domain and then filter (or sort) by the is_admin field. Can we add an index to index.yaml which will work? Currently if we filter users by is_admin then we receive an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two options you listed are pretty much all you get:

1. Using indexes: re-save all the entities again with `indexed=False` removed (could be very expensive but one time only if you have lots of existing `DomainUser` entities).
2. Not using indexes at all: query by the `domain` property only and filter the results in python (could be very expensive each time if you have lots of users in each `domain` depending on how often you run the query), i.e.:

```
 all_users = DomainUser.query(DomainUser.domain == 'xxx').fetch()
 admins = [u for u in all_users if u.is_admin]
 users = [u for u in all_users if not u.is_admin]
```

You will need to decide for yourself which option would be cheaper / faster if that's what you're after.

Comment: We can only search in Python for domain names with up to 250 users, otherwise it takes too much time.